# GA Custom Event with User-ID triggered thru the API, Views question

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this scenario.

I have **User-ID** feature enabled in my GA with **session unification** ON.

Inside my app when user logging I push **userId** to dataLayer and then I publish the custom event.

Inside my "All View" I can see **2** users witch is good (since merging still did not happen) and inside my User-ID View I can see just user with set User-ID

Now, the thing I noticed is that when the custom event that is published from the client is showing in both Non UserID and UserID Views.

But when I publish Custom Event from the Server thru the API, With only passing User-ID That event is only showing inside User-ID View.

My question is is this expected? Or should I publish the Event from the Client directly through API with User-Id, or Session Unification will do the job and I'll only have 1 event showing instead of two, meaning that it will figure out that Event is actually associated to that specific User?

Thanks!

Comment: Shows the measurement protocol you use to send the event, pls.

Comment: HI! @MichelePisani I'm using this endpoint 

https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&tid=trackingId&uid=uid&ec=eventCategoryea=eventAction&el=eventLabel

From what I found inside the documentation and it's showing data properly inside User-ID View, but not inside All Data View, I believe that's going to happen when the merge is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the endpoint you are using the problem is definitely due to the fact that you are sending only the `uid` parameter and not the `cid` as well.

In order for the hit to be successful, only one of the two `uid` or `cid` parameters can be sent, however by sending only the `uid` the hit will be shown only in the User-ID view.

Comment: That makes sense thanks! Just one question since from the frontend I'm sending event where I set UserID (and since it's sent from the frontend seems like both CID and UID are sent at that point)

And on the backend I'm triggering the Event for that user by UID, 

I have session unification ON, will that figure out it's the same User? 

Thanks! 

(Also in one of my reports I'm not seeing date from yesterday still, but It was showing in reltime yesterday, do I need to wait or it can be something else?)

Comment: In the User-ID view, if the uid is the same it recognizes the user even if the cid is different. In standard views, however, if the cid is different it will be another user.

Comment: Perfect! So technically If I want to take a report when Signed In user-triggered some Action I will do those reports inside User-ID Views, 

And for the Signed In Goal I believe I can see that inside regular View since I have User ID custom dimension too